# exercise concerning the inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, potential-energy, newtonian-mechanics

I have an exercise to ask yourself.

> A ball of mass m = 5 g starts at rest and travels 50 cm along a ramp
> inclined at 45 ° to the horizontal. a) If we imagine frictionless motion
> of the ball along the ramp, compute the speed of the ball at the bottom of the ramp.
> What is the change in potential energy of the ball?

My idea is to use the gravitational acceleration, multiply it by the cosine of $45°$ and find the x-component of the gravitational acceleration, and finally use the formula $ v^2=v_0^2 +2*g*x $ to find the speed at the end of the ramp.

For the second point, my idea is to use this formula $ m*g*h $. 
My idea is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your ideas are good, they should get you the right answers. Be sure to take care when calculating the change in height for m*g*h. Does this answer your question?